# Cannot make whole TouchableWithFeedback component clickable React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to make a *slider menu* in Android. Therefor I made `TouchableNativeFeedback` with a View parent and Icon and text children wrapped in. Problem is the whole component isn´t clickable. Only the first **10%** from the left hand side is clickable.

I have tried deleting all styling and switch to `TouchableOpacity`, *TouchableWithoutFeedback* and `TouchableHighlight`, but problem still remains.

```
import React from 'react'

import {View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
TouchableOpacity,
Platform
} from "react-native";

var DrawerMenuItem = React.createClass({

propTypes: {
 onClick: React.PropTypes.func,
 text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
 iconName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
},

 render: function() {
 return(


   name={this.props.iconName}
   size={24}
   color={colors.lightBlack}
    />
   {this.props.text}


 )
 }

 });

 module.exports = DrawerMenuItem;`
```

And in DrawerContent.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import DrawerMenuItem from './DrawerMenuItem'
import {View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
TouchableOpacity,
TouchableNativeFeedback,
BackAndroid,
ScrollView,
Image,
Platform
} from "react-native";

var DrawerContent = React.createClass({

propTypes: {
onClick: React.PropTypes.func,
resetStack: React.PropTypes.func,
closeDrawer: React.PropTypes.func,
},

 _onPress: function(viewToShow){
this.props.onClick(viewToShow);
this.props.closeDrawer();
},

render: function() {
return (

<View>
  <View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
      <Text>{reduxStore.getState().user.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <Image resizeMode='cover' source={require('../../resources/images/rf_logo_vit.png')}></Image>
</View>
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.menu}>
  <View>
    <DrawerMenuItem onClick={() => {this._onPress('##')}} iconName='line-chart' text={'###'}/>
    <DrawerMenuItem onClick={() => {this._onPress('##')}} iconName='bar-chart' text={'###'}/>
    <DrawerMenuItem onClick={() => {this._onPress('##')}} iconName='bullseye' text={Localize('###')}/>
    <DrawerMenuItem onClick={() => {this._onPress('##')}} iconName='phone' text={Localize('###')}/>
    <DrawerMenuItem onClick={() => {this._onPress('##')}} iconName='file-text' text={Localize('###')}/>


  </View>
  </ScrollView>
</View>

);
}
});
```

`DrawerContent` is the slider menu and its working. But only the first **10%** of the component is clickable. I wish to make the whole component clickable. I mean everything inside *TouchableNativeFeedback*. Right now it only half of the Icon.

> React Native version: 0.31.0 Platform(s) Android (also same problem in
>   IOS) Operating System: macOS

Comment: There is some code missing in your `DrawerMenuItem` example. Can you put together a working sample on https://rnplay.org/?

Comment: Sorry did make a github instead: https://github.com/Henny777/myApp

Comment: Now I made it work: https://rnplay.org/apps/dy0GCA

Comment: oh sorry I didnt mean I made application work, I meant rnplay.org

Comment: You can't just copy/paste your code in rnplay.org ; you have to actually try and make it work to reproduce your bug. Otherwise it is impossible to help you, short of rewriting everything for you.